# Adding a subdomain name to the main domain name in php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am currently developing a web project and was hoping if I could make this happen.

So, suppose `http://schoolblock.edu` was a custom domain name through changing the `hosts` and `httpd-vhosts.conf` files.

Now, I would like so that `http://students.schoolblock.edu` could be created dynamically without having to add it in the files mentioned above. It could be from something like `index.php?access=students` and the `$_GET['access']` to be what is prepended in `schoolblocks.edu`.

All I need is a clear explanation and preferably an example on how I could make it work.

Comment: DNS wildcard... although that has to be in DNS, not a simple entry in your local HOSTS file.

Comment: How would I achieve this?

Comment: It's a really complex chain of events.  You need to have your DNS service add a wildcard entry for *.yourdomain.com.  Your server configuration (I'm thinking Apache, what we use mostly) will have to point to your default site for any entry that doesn't exist, and your default site will have to be coded to read the requested URL and either make redirects or include appropriate code to appropriately handle the requested subdomain.